# No Entity Data Model (EDMX) Template with Visual Studio 2010 SP1 & ADO.NET Entity Framework 4.1

Tags: visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, ado.net, webmatrix, edmx

I'm having a lot of issues with the templates of Visual Studio 2010 SP1 & ADO.NET Entity Framework 4.1

I noticed that other people had these problems, and asked similar questions, but I don't think they gave enough information to make it solve-able.

The Problem: **ADO.NET Entity Data Model Templates are not appearing whatsoever**

Screenshot: http://c0848462.cdn.cloudfiles.rackspacecloud.com/f067439f6e8f25d5fd36761fd1efc88a74fd765ff1.png

### Solution File

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 11.00
# Visual Studio 2010
Project("{E24C65DC-7377-472B-9ABA-BC803B73C61A}") = "localhost", "http://localhost:36626", "{9BA46BAD-E736-4943-ACAD-EDE2E7A1A21E}"
    ProjectSection(WebsiteProperties) = preProject
        UseIISExpress = "true"
        TargetFrameworkMoniker = ".NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.0"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.VirtualPath = "/localhost_36626"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.PhysicalPath = "..\..\My Web Sites\Jantire\"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.TargetPath = "PrecompiledWeb\localhost_36626\"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.Updateable = "true"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.ForceOverwrite = "true"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.FixedNames = "false"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.Debug = "True"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.VirtualPath = "/localhost_36626"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.PhysicalPath = "..\..\My Web Sites\Jantire\"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.TargetPath = "PrecompiledWeb\localhost_36626\"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.Updateable = "true"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.ForceOverwrite = "true"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.FixedNames = "false"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.Debug = "False"
        SlnRelativePath = "..\..\My Web Sites\Jantire\"
    EndProjectSection
EndProject
Global
    GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
        Debug|Any CPU = Debug|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
        {9BA46BAD-E736-4943-ACAD-EDE2E7A1A21E}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {9BA46BAD-E736-4943-ACAD-EDE2E7A1A21E}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution
        HideSolutionNode = FALSE
    EndGlobalSection
EndGlobal
```

Relevant System Specs:

- Visual Studio 2010 Professional SP1
- ADO.NET Entity Data Model 4.1
- ASP.NET MVC 3 Tools Update
- Windows 7 x64 SP1
- WebMatrix

I'm coding this using both WebMatrix and Visual Studio 2010 Professional SP1

Comment: Is there any solution for this? I am facing similar issue. I can see EF 4.0 in the add/remove programs.

Comment: Screenshot link is broken.

Answer (score 57):

Open the install media for VS2010 and browse to ":\WCU\EFTools".
Her you will find two files:

ADONETEntityFrameworkTools_enu.msi

ADONETEntityFrameworkTools_enu.cab

1. Copy those files to a folder on your PC.
2. Create a log file in the folder - for instance with the name "Log.txt"
3. Open a cmd prompt (possibly run the cmd prompt as administrator) and navigate to the
   folder with the msi and cap files.
4. Run this command:

   ADONETEntityFrameworkTools_enu.msi USING_EXUIH=1 /log "Log.txt"

It will take a while to install so be patient.

The installation should now be visible in "Control Panel -> Installed Programs" as "Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 ADO.NET Entity Framework Tools".

The items template should be visible in Visual Studio when adding a new item to a project. (Add New Item->Data->ADO.NET Entity Data Model).

More info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee225240.aspx

Comment: Cool. Worked for me. Note that it didn't work in the first place. I had to uninstall "Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 ADO.NET Entity Framework Tools" from Add/Remove Programs panel and again install it using the method described above.

Comment: Thanks! You helped me fix the same problem with VS11 beta. For VS11 the folder is x:\packages\EFTools and you just need to copy the EFTools.msi file onto your computer and run it. Worked great!

Comment: I didn't have to run the specified files in your answer, but it led to to EFTools.msi in my installation media that did the trick for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

Actually, you will have to add simple class library project, and do "Add New Item" and then you will find ADO.NET Entity Data model.

(It seems from newer versions, they have removed this project template, and offering it as "New Item". I was  searching for it, then found it like new item instead of new project template.  though this MSDN link shows ado.net entity data model as new project :( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ff830362

Answer (score 3):

When you install Visual Studio there is separate component called **Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 ADO.NET Entity Framework Tools**. You can check that this component is installed in your computer simply by checking installed programs. If the component is not installed you must probably install it again from VS intallation media.

You mentioned that you have a Professional version but still I would expect that your Add New Item will contain much more features - I don't see groups for Windows Forms, WPF and Workflow - all valid groups. It looks like your installation is somehow incomplete or you are using some project template that perhaps don't offer all groups.

Installing EF 4.1 will not add necessary parts from EF 4 which are part of VS installation. EF 4.1 has these features as prerequisity.

Comment: That specific project hid a lot of different templates, but Entity Framework isn't something it hides. Here's a screenshot of the missing template groups, and ADO.NET Entity Framework Tools being installed http://i56.tinypic.com/1zo7ue1.png

Comment: Which template does the project use? Which version of .NET is used in that template?

Answer (score 2):

My solution was that my brand new project was inexplicably set to use .NET 2.0 in the project settings. Once I set it to 4.5, the template appeared.

Answer (score 1):

The template could be downloaded from the following link.

[microsoft.com ADO.net 4.1 download](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=8363)

Comment: The fastest way to get the template!

Answer (score 1):

Restoring default project templates proposed in the majidgeek answer did not help me (with Visual Studio 2012).

Repairing Visual Studio neither.

I had used a Web Installer from MSDN to install VS2012, so i had no installation media to apply the solution suggested in the AH. answer.

However, the accepted answer from here solved my problem:

http://www.datazx.cn/Fv7p5a/xw-US/oaax2pu/2q7xs6/d8x6rssc-b4mt-fsix-bc6c-ct8mf8d6fsbc23rsdfd.html

> I finally figured it out. I ran EFTools.msi from a C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\ subfolder, which only allowed me to 'uninstall' or 'repair'. I tried repair, but I get the same problem, so I did 'uninstall', then ran it again and it allowed 'install'. After this install, I can now add Entity Data Models.

Also, the accepted answer in the "Missing Entity Framework Template in Visual Studio 2012 Express for Web" threat on forums.asp.net suggests that repairing Entity Framework Designer for Visual Studio 2012 enu via 'Start -> Control Panel -> Programs and Features' might work as well (I can post only two links with my current 1 point Stackoverflow reputation, so I won't provide the exact source).

Another possible solution:

> My Problem was: Visual Studio is installed on Drive D:\, whereas the Entity Framework Installer placed the Package in c:...\VisualStudio 10.0\Common7....\ItemTemplates folder.
>   --> Copied the AdoNetEntityDataModelCSharp.zip to drive d: and ran devenv /installvstemplates.
>   This fixxed it for me.
>   Edit:
>   Also had to copy Various DLLs from IDE folder, PrivateAssemblies and PublicAssemblies.
>   then run devenv /ResetSkipPkgs

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c059069b-eae4-48b4-a06e-ffd5f186077b/adonet-data-entity-model-template-missing-in-vs-2010-ultimate?forum=adodotnetentityframework

I also installed VS in a non-default path (different disk partition), so it indeed may be one of the potential causes of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had uninstalled VS2012 Ultimate trial and installed VS2012 Premuim and had this happen. In Windows 7 Control Panel\Programs\Programs and Features I found "Entity Framework Designer for Visual Studio 2012 - enu and did a repair and that fixed everything.

Answer (score 0):

try [Restore Default Project Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247116.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

if you already installed full VS and template not appears try to run VS2010 setup and and click `Repair/Reinstall` and after that processing finished,restart system.

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to add the template. I had to reinstall the EntityFramework 4.1 and then reinstall the visual studio templates. Here are the steps:

1. Install EntityFramework 4.1 from http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=8363
2. Using Visual Studio command prompt, navigate to IDE, run devenv /installvstemplates

Answer (score 0):

search in C:\ProgramData\Package Cache for EFTools.msi and install the latest.