# Can't open EDMX-file in designer

Tags: visual-studio-2010, edmx, edmx-designer

It opens as XML file only.
In MS VS 2010 Ultimate + SP1.

I need to open it in model-designer.

What can I do??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On the file in the solution explorer try

Right Click > Open With > ADO.NET Entity Data Model Designer

[image]

Comment: I have no option like this. Also, I even have no ADO.NET ENTITY MODEL via "add item" menu!

Comment: @Monochromie Do you have the "open with" option?

Comment: Seems you may need to (re) install the entity framework tools. This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5696436/no-entity-data-model-edmx-template-with-visual-studio-2010-sp1-ado-net-entit

Answer (score 1):

I've came across the same problem in Visual Studio 2015,i tried to open the file with

```
Right Click > Open With > ADO.NET Entity Data Model Designer
```

and the option is not there.From there i realized my installation of Visual Studio 2015 must be without some components, so i went back to setup and installed Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools and Microsoft Web Developer Tools.Finally it worked ! The options are there when you open from solution and the file can be opened

[Components that i added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTDOZ.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Adds references to the System.Data, System.Data.Entity, System.Core, System.Security, and System.Runtime.Serialization assemblies to the project, if they do not already exist.